# How to write artificial intelligence in .net ( C # )

Tags: c#, .net

I want to write some code that need to use artificial intelligence. 
I dont know how to do it.

Is there some libraries that i can use for this ? 
Is there some .net environment ( something like Prolog ) that i can use ?

Comment: "I want to write some code that need to use artificial intelligence. I dont know how to do it. " - erm, noone does! pseudo-artificial intelligence, maybe...

Comment: How do you know that what you need is exactly AI then?

Comment: ML.NET (Machine Learning and AI Framework) https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/apps/machine-learning-and-ai

Comment: ironic that a question having so many upvotes and 'favorites' gets closed down because of some.

Comment: Happily Microsoft has recently developed and released a new framework called ML.NET specifically for machine learning which is awesome! Check it out!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Artificial intelligence is an *immense* field with many subdisciplines.  The particular library you'll want will almost certainly be a function of what you're trying to do.

Are you trying to do some sort of machine learning (regression, for example)?  Then you'll probably want to find a library containing state-of-the art classifiers, like neural networks, SVMs, boosted decision trees, k-means classifiers, etc.

Are you trying to develop robot control systems?  Then you'll probably want to look into particle filters, Kalman filters, probabilistic road maps, etc.

Are you trying to do computer vision or speech recognition?  Then you might want access to signal processing libraries in addition to the aforementioned machine learning tools.

Are you trying to have the computer play a game?  Then you might want libraries for minimax, UCT (my personal favorite!), or Monte Carlo simulation.

In short, there are a huge number of libraries out there.  Identifying what particular problem you want to solve will be the first step toward finding one appropriate for your uses.

Answer (score 23):

You want to work with **AForge**, http://code.google.com/p/aforge/

> AForge.NET Framework is a C# framework
>   designed for developers and
>   researchers in the fields of Computer
>   Vision and Artificial Intelligence -
>   image processing, neural networks,
>   genetic algorithms, machine learning,
>   robotics, etc.

The framework is comprised by the set of libraries and sample applications, which demonstrate their features: http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/

I use it for Imaging for a few years now, works great every time ;)

Answer (score 8):

If you want to work with Genetic Algorithms, try to use [GeneticSharp](https://github.com/giacomelli/geneticsharp)

> A fast, extensible, multi-platform and multithreading .NET Genetic
>   Algorithm library that simplifies the development of applications
>   using Genetic Algorithms (GAs).

The library implements the fullset of GA's operators: selection, crossover, mutation, reinsertion and termination. Moreover, it has a lot of operators implementations:

**Selections**

- Elite (also know as Truncate or Truncation)
- Roulette Wheel
- Stochastic Universal Sampling
- Tournament

**Crossovers**

- Cut and Splice
- Cycle (CX)
- One-Point
- Ordered OX1
- Partially Mapped (PMX)
- Three parent
- Two-Point
- Uniform

**Mutations**

- Reverse Sequence (RSM)
- Twors
- Uniform

**Reinsertions**

- Elitist
- Fitness Based
- Pure
- Uniform

**Terminations**

- Generation number
- Time evolving
- Fitness stagnation
- Fitness threshold
- And e Or (allows combine others terminations)

Answer (score 5):

Check out [Infra.Net](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/infernet/) library. It's a part of Microsoft Research projects and contains good resources.

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of SDKs available for  AI(Artificial Intelligence) like this [example](http://www.anticipatingminds.com) but always the programming logic is yours !!